# Driver for Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller

Tags: drivers, sound, 20.04

I'v looked every where and cannot find an answer to my problem. Every tutorial still says dummy output this is really annoying and need help.

So how do I get the audio drivers for Intel Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller?

I'v tried additional drivers which don't not work.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to get my speakers to run on my x5 z8300 atom laptop for a week, and this seems to finally have solved it:

Run

```sh
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and add `915.disable_power_well=0` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. If you have for example

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

you'd replace it with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i915.disable_power_well=0 quiet splash"
```

Found here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1256655